# Easyui combobox press enter automatically clear the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I have a problem with easyui combobox, when ı press enter after type, if value is do not exist in combobox, automatically clear the box. I cant get the text value.

How can i cancel it...

```
  <input class="easyui-combobox" id="productPK" name="productPK" style="width:200px"  required="required" data-options="valueField:'id',textField:'text'"/>
```

//script

```
var t = $('#productPK'); 
t.combobox('textbox').bind('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){   // when press ENTER key,           
      alert($(this).val()); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#productPK').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){   // when press ENTER key,           
      alert($(this).val()); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.8/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.8/js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>

<input class="easyui-combobox" id="productPK" name="productPK" style="width:200px"  required="required" data-options="valueField:'id',textField:'text'"/>
```

Please check if you want the same

Thanks

Comment: I am using this  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>  thanks for answer but dont work.